# PHP network monitoring debian

Tags: php, network-monitoring

My plan is to monitor network activity/usage on eth0 on my debian wheezy 7.1 using php. Could this done be done somehow by php? Does exist some library for this? Or should I use exec() and parse the output?

Would be really thankful for every tutorial, suggestion or a tip, thanks!

Comment: You could try to parse the output of wireshark, but this will be much work. Please keep in mind that also the (http) request will create new TCP packages. If you just want to read some general network stats you could also simple read the proc folder of your filesystem.

Comment: What about if I have installed like 'nethogs', I would need to launch the app and then terminate it, am I right? The reason why do I need this is to obtain actual transfer rates sent/received bytes.

Comment: The transfer rates of a connection or of all connections?

Comment: Of all connections at present time, since nethogs outputs all connections

Comment: I expect that this information is also somewhere hidden in this file: /proc/net/netstat

Comment: I would have to parse it way too long, anyway, what if I would like to get information about IP:PORT and their Download/Upload speed? netstat is overall traffic if I'm not mistaken :/

Comment: I don't know how to get the traffic stats about connections. That file mented above is someting else than the netstat command, but yes they give back similar data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info you need is in /proc/net/dev

```
# cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:  177937    1304    0    0    0     0          0         0   177937    1304    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0:16268834   14619    0    0    0 10091          0         0  1201136   10555   20    0    0     0       0          0
```

For the transfer rate you will have to calculate the delta from the previous capture but the value will be approximate.